# Angular <app-root> is not recognized in Node views

Tags: node.js, angular

I am building a MEAN app, and have run into a problem I have not faced before.  When I include my app-root selector in my index.ejs file in the Node views, the selector is not recognized and is discarded.  The editor shows this error:

```
<app-root> is not recognized!  Discarding Unexpected <app-root>
```

I checked the selector in the App Component to make sure the selector matched, checked the AppModule to make sure I was declaring it, and checked the main.ts to make sure I was bootstrapping correctly.  Everything looks fine, and there isn't an error in the terminal when I run the app.  I've spent about an hour looking for similar questions here and in the Angular documentation, but haven't found anything.

So I'm curious whether anyone else has faced this problem or has an idea of what's happening.  Code below.

## index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

  <script src="/js/app/bundle.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

## App Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

## App Module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routes } from './route/app.routing';
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AmChartsModule } from "amcharts3-angular2";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';

//Services
import { NewsApiService } from './service/news-api.service';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MapComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    AmChartsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [NewsApiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

## main.ts

```
import './polyfills';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

## dependencies

```
{
  "name": "aether-news",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./server/bin/www",
    "build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^4.2.5",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.16.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.2",
    "debug": "^2.6.3",
    "ejs": "~2.5.5",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "hbs": "^4.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.2",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^2.2.1",
    "preboot": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "del-cli": "^1.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks for taking a look...

Comment: Have you try placing bundle.js before app-root tag.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Yeah I've tried that.  The error was actually showing before I bundled the app.

Comment: What are you using to compile your project? The `... is not expected!` message comes from HTML Tidy (http://www.html-tidy.org/). It appears that there are options to disable the removal of unrecognized elements (https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues/119), but HTML Tidy should not be necessary or even useful with the vast majority of Angular applications. I don't see any imports of HTML Tidy included in the standard dependencies pulled in by Angular CLI 1.2.0.

Comment: I double checked all my packages in my Atom editor and I don't have an HTML Tidy installed.  It is odd, as I've created other MEAN apps and haven't had this error.  I'll add my dependencies above, maybe there's something in it you might see as the culprit?  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<app-root>` is AngularJS selector, and your ejs was bootstrapped by nodeJS ejs engine, it won't recognize the AngularJS selector.

just compile your angularJS project by using "ng build" command, then copy all contents in "dist" fold to the "public" fold of your nodejs project (or you need to config the dist path in your nodejs project), it should work, you don't need the index.ejs at all.